# glClientWaitSync does not work after Lollipop (android 5.0) update

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am developing an app using OpenGL ES 3.0.
And the target device is Google Nexus 5 (Adreno 320) and Saumsung Galaxy S5 (Adreno 420) .

I use `glFenceSync` and `glClientWaitSync` to measure the processing time of each render cycles I coded when android version 4.4.

However, after Lollipop update, it seems to `glFenceSync` and `glClientWaitSync` immediately returns. So, I can't measure the processing time.

Why is this happening?
Is this an Adreno graphics driver's bug or a Lollipop bug?

---

This is a part of my code.

```
GLsync syncFence1 = glFenceSync(GL_SYNC_GPU_COMMANDS_COMPLETE, 0);
glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4, 1);
GLenum syncResult1 = glClientWaitSync(syncFence1, GL_SYNC_FLUSH_COMMANDS_BIT, 1000000000);
glDeleteSync(syncFence1);
```

I was to stop a CPU operation until glDrawArraysInstanced function all finished, so the graphics pipeline operation finished.
And I confirmed the timeout is longer than the graphics pipeline operation time.

Comment: glFenceSync is supposed to immediately return anyway, it just creates a sync object and gives you a handle to it. ClientWaitSync has multiple possible behaviors, you're going to need to show the actual arguments you passed it and what it returned.

Comment: Oh, I misquentioned. Well actually glFenceSync returns immediately. What I really want to talk about is glClientWaitSync. I added the actual code of my program. Please see it and answer what do you think about it. Thank you.

Comment: What is the value of `syncResult1`, i.e. the return value of `glClientWaitSync()`?

Comment: @RetoKoradi - The value of syncResult1 is GL_CONDITION_SATISFIED.